# std::make_unique invoking private constructor from friend class

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I am seeing a behavior of `std::make_unique` while creating an object from a `friend` class. The following is a minimum reproducible example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
    
class A 
{
    friend class B;
    private: 
    A() = default;
};
    
class B 
{
    private: 
    std::unique_ptr<A> dPtr;
    public: 
    B() 
    {
        //dPtr = std::make_unique<A>(); // This is a compiler error
        dPtr = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A()); // This is working 
    }
};
```

Compiled with: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

From what I understand, `std::make_unique` is a template function that is not actually a `friend` of `class A`. How can I make `std::make_unique` a `friend` function of `class A`, so that `std::make_unique` will work in my example?

Comment: `friend unique_ptr<A> make_unique<A>();` I'm not sure this is well-defined though; there's some wording in the standard about how the implementation may change signatures of library functions (as long as calls behave as if original signatures are in place), though that wording only seems to apply to member functions.

Comment: I don't understand the goal of the exercise though. Presumably, you made the constructor private and made `B` a friend so that only `B` could create instances of `A`. If you now make `make_unique` a friend, then anyone would once again be able to create instances of `A` this way, defeating the purpose. At that point, you might as well make the constructor public and be done with it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i am working on a design pattern where i want to construct A object only through B class. Code i have pasted is only MRE.

Comment: Precisely my point. If you declare `make_unique<A>` a friend, then any piece of code would be able to call `make_unique<A>()`, even if it can't call `new A()`. In my humble opinion, you would be better off *not* declaring `make_unique` a friend, and sticking with `std::unique_ptr<A>(new A())` in `B`

Comment: Yes. that is right. Consider A class as HTML Tag and B is HTML builder and B is holding an unique_ptr of root HTML tag. HTML Tag is also holding a list of its child HTML Tags. I don't want HTML Tag created independently without HTML builder. Make sense ?

Comment: You are answering a question I haven't asked. I'm not sure what the point of that long explanation was - it doesn't change anything I said earlier. Again - if you don't want `HTMLTag` creatable outside `HTMLBuilder`, then you likely do **not** want to declare `make_unique<HTMLTag>` a friend of `HTMLTag`. That does mean that `HTMLBuilder` is also unable to use `make_unique<HTMLTag>`; it'll have to manage without.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry. You question was on code after adding "friend unique_ptr<A> make_unique<A>();" and i was explaining you my original intention of design.Yes adding line "friend unique_ptr<A> make_unique<A>();" will defeat the purpose of making ctor private. So that should be good way to handle this?